# JQuery Mobile collapsible widget collapse and expand events not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I have a page of dynamically created JQuery 1.3.1 collapsible items (not in an accordion set), and I am trying to save the expanded or collapsed state of each item. The collapsible items work fine without attaching any handlers. My code to attach the handlers is here, which I'm calling in `pagebeforeshow` (I tried in `pageshow` as well):

```
function bindCollapsibleHistoryHandlers(){
    function getHandler(field, value){
        var handler = function(event, ui){
            var element = event.target.id;
            var id = (element.split('-'))[1];
            var status = window.mam_history.status('meetings', id);
            if (null == status){
                status = { "open": false, "note_open": false, "dist_open": false };
            }
            status[field] = value;
            var new_status = null;
            window.mam_history.status('meetings', id, status);
                        return true;
        }
        return handler;
    }

    $('.mtg_item').off('collapsiblecollapse');
    $('.mtg_item').on('collapsible', getHandler('open', false));
    $('.mtg_item').off('collapsibleexpand');
    $('.mtg_item').on('collapsibleexpand', getHandler('open', true));

    $('.dist_info').off('collapsiblecollapse');
    $('.dist_info').on('collapsiblecollapse', getHandler('dist_open', false));
    $('.dist_info').off('collapsibleexpand');
    $('.dist_info').on('collapsibleexpand', getHandler('dist_open', true));
}
```

One of the HTML elements looks like this in the Chrome inspector:

[image]

According to the [JQuery Mobile 1.3.1 documentation](http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/#option-collapsed), the events to trap are `collapsiblecollapse` and `collapsibleexpand`. When I try using these, the event handlers never get called. Looking on the web I replaced these events with `collapse` and `expand`. With these, the event handler would be called when the collapsible was clicked, but the collapsible widget would not collapse or expand either before or after the handler ran. It's not just a visual issue, because the state of the collapsible as read with `.collapsible('option', 'collapsed')` did not change either.

Inside the handler I tried various combinations of adding or removing the `ui-collapsible-collapsed` class or setting the `collapsible` option before a `.trigger('create')`, and even triggering the `collapsiblecollapse` and `collapsibleexpand` inside the handler (when it was bound to `collapse` and `expand`, of course). Removing the `.off()` lines made no difference (I can't imagine why it would). Nothing I've tried so far will cause the collapsible to collapse or expand when clicked on when the handler actually runs while bound to `collapse` or `expand`. It doesn't matter what code is actually in the handler, or whether I have a `data-collapsed` attribute in the `<div>` tag to begin with or not.

So it seems there's something I'm missing, and I would appreciate any help in seeing the error in my ways.

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle, wanna check html codes after appending?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution

#### Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/3pCQh/

As you have notices proper way to detect collapsible state is to use collapse and expand event (information provided in official documentation is wrong). Also when binding events in **`jQuery Mobile`**, specially with dynamically created objects it is important to use  delegated binding, like this:

```
$(document).on( "collapse", "#test-collapsible", function( event, ui ){
    alert('Close');
});

$(document).on( "expand", "#test-collapsible", function( event, ui ){
    alert('Open');
});
```

This example doesn't care if object exist or don't exist. Event is going to be bound to document object and it will propagate to the correct destination only if/when object becomes available inside the **`DOM`**.

### Few notes

If you use correct page event (like **`pageinit`**) you don't need to use **`off`** to unbind an event. **`Pageinit`** will trigger only once, just like document ready when used with classic jQuery.

There's one more thing. If you are using several **`HTML`** pages you need to be careful with your javascript. When jQuery Mobile loads additional **`HTML`** pages it loads only **`BODY`** content so everything inside a **`HEAD`** will be discarded. This could also be the reason why your code example is not executing. Solutions to this problem can be fond **[HERE](http://www.gajotres.net/how-jquery-mobile-page-handling-affects-javascript-executions/)**.

Comment: Changing the on() to delegated binding worked. Thanks so much!